# Auto Clear Data Validation in same row when data is entered

Tags: excel, vba

I have come up with the following which I'm trying to use to clear the Data validation in the cell (same row, column W) when a value is entered into a cell in column V.
I have a drop down data selection in column W, which I am trying to wipe clean for the same row whenever I enter data in column V. For example, if data is entered in V4, cell W4 is now a blank cell with no validation.

Any thoughts on why I can't get this to work?

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim wsSource As Worksheet
    Dim rowCount As Long


    Set wsSource = Worksheets("Attributes")

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    With wsSource
    rowCount = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "V").End(xlUp).Row 
    For i = 1 To rowCount
        If .Cells(i, "V").Value <> 0 Then

        ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
        Range.Cells(i, "W").ClearContents
            With Selection.Validation
            .Delete
            .Add Type:=xlValidateInputOnly, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator _
            :=xlBetween
            .IgnoreBlank = True
            .InCellDropdown = True
            .InputTitle = ""
            .ErrorTitle = ""
            .InputMessage = ""
            .ErrorMessage = ""
            .ShowInput = True
            .ShowError = True
            End With
        End If
    Next i
    End With


End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems the problems are in this lines:

```
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select 'delete this one because is selecting column by column

Cells(i, "W").ClearContents 'delete `Range.` it is redundant
```

If you want just clean the data in the column W you just need:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim wsSource As Worksheet
    Dim rowCount As Long

    Set wsSource = Worksheets("Attributes")

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    With wsSource
    rowCount = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "V").End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 1 To rowCount
        If .Cells(i, "V").Value <> 0 Then
        Cells(i, "W").ClearContents
        End If
    Next i
    End With
End Sub
```